# Alternate to get access token from challenge handler response WL.Client.getLastAccessToken

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to use the accessToken from a custom challenge handler. We want to send that accessToken and token id to an external service. that will validate the token by calling mobile first token validation endpoint.

How to read access token and token ID. In MFP 6.3 we have WL.Client.getLastAccessToken that has been deprecated. Is there any API which read the access token received for a challenge handler.

obtainAccessToken

obtainAccessToken(scope, onSuccess, onFailure)
Obtains an OAuth 2.0 access token from the Worklight server. The token is required in order to send a request to an external server which uses this Worklight authentication method.

Parameters:

scope - Optional. The name of the security test protecting the external resource. If the scope is null, a token for the application's default security test will be obtained.

onSuccess - The success callback. Note that there is no need to parse the response. Instead, use WL.Client.getLastAccessToken(scope) in order to get the last obtained token.

onFailure - The failure callback.

**Deprecated:**
**Since version 7.0**

Is there any alternate API in MobileFirst 7.1

Response Data: {"access_token":"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.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.qiej5KRanOOx_sjdCgdl8cFVLC88_V1yIcAML2GetHEjH8-ORyabJ0Ax0kjgEU5tMgEh6wg7A0LeW9rcZR_A9K5biLEQRJBvqcjKzedmq9DFYB_GluRL0W7pDyOk2ZpRBKQm5FXsxjKKda-yVd_7i7ipfYjMqUWctcloeXelDkPxbfxVxB1X7lyqmihflvE3ir9UG7WkxxbEAtZIUIdMkmmwCoitlTTjKPLjHfihlEJQQEm59jgXuBv2l62nWVG9eoqNnTCuYH3PlpiDK1YyK0ThBZxjAa2pLkOH1myPQRH2e-rfwJlaOit5ZosEm7pwXM2AEnvKNYyhw_2RPAnLVA","scope":"wl_antiXSRFRealm CustomAuthenticatorRealm wl_directUpdateRealm wl_remoteDisableRealm wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm wl_anonymousUserRealm","id_token":"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.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.ojcboxmS-7pQqTx1ebugTuUalbO61_HGmpVSi6_XbIQ_VCknq1zAjRgMeU0NWeaKPHDZiZlEr-nst9EUKzlKvdQNJfDZ-jjF-Nw1IVV0bfy5_YfrDWju3gY5gzNmxi188SydKxDVf6Ncv02YA6SpNU2XaoArrfGnkhmjbEaZUaWj9e8SF9xbMmaNgDfKOQs2WFJZfRY2DdkG1YodVPipxbtD81Bw4rZ-vroAkXZznd9meWmTZx9bxKtNcMqtala8NFvR6hHiLfKZuZno7FjVv26UV8pfHuLed24fHuMAxhD2wLCKfo6ZDarrcWRVZb30tJZ0AD4mGhnV6Y5PxFO7ng","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For migrating from 6.3 to 7.1,
Please refer to ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/… , I see that you can use WLauthorizationManager.getCachedAuthorizationHeader() available in 7.1

from 7.1 to 8.0 ,

Please refer here Alternate API's for deprecated APIs in 7.1 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devref/c_sdk_changes4migration.html

In this particular scenario, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-worklight-android-native/html/com/worklight/wlclient/api/WLAuthorizationManager.html has to be used.

Have you tried WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken(scope) ?

Comment: Hi Kavitha, Thank. We are still in MobileFirst 7.1 not 8.0. I don't see any supporting document for MobileFirst 7.1.

Comment: Ragu, Please refer to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/what_s_new/c_deprecations.html    , I see that you can use WLauthorizationManager.getCachedAuthorizationHeader() available in 7.1

Comment: Hi Kavitha, I tried and getting null. Do you have a working sample. Thanks.

Comment: All good. Seems API reference document is not valid for WLauthorizationManager class. Thanks Kavi